# wiremock request matching with comparison between two query parameters

Tags: java, kotlin, stub, wiremock, ohhttpstubs

I am using wiremock (to mock our Rest API) for selenium tests. I have a rest end point like `http://localhost:8080/compare-date?from=2018-03-01&to=2018-03-10`

For this, we are trying to create some intelligent mock using `Java`, which will be invoked only when `to` date is less than the `from` date. Ex: `http://localhost:8080/compare-date?from=2018-03-01&to=2018-02-10`

But, i am unable to achieve this. Kindly suggest how this can be done. Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Dharani

Answer (score 1):

At the moment your best bet would be to create a custom `RequestMatcher` implementation that can determine whether a date falls between the query parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible with **LinqMatcher** from the C# .NET Version from [WireMock.Net](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net).

Example JSON to match your request can be:

```js
{
    "Request": {
        "Path": {
            "Matchers": [
                {
                    "Name": "WildcardMatcher",
                    "Pattern": "/linq"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Params": [
            {
                "Name": "from",
                "Matchers": [
                    {
                        "Name": "LinqMatcher",
                        "Pattern": "DateTime.Parse(it) > \"2018-03-01 00:00:00\""
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Body": {}
    },
    "Response": {
        "Body": "linq match !!!"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should already expect the response as part of your test. That being said, if you want this functionality from your stub, then you will have to extend it.

There are a number of ways you can extend WireMock, most of them are found on this page: http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/.

Honestly, I would probably use specific years for particular response and create rules for them.